# IP address restriction for specific users - AWS / Cognito / IAM / API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm building a serverless web application using API Gateway and Lambda, which restricts API call to registered users by Cognito and IAM. We have individual / enterprise users and want to put additional access restriction for specific enterprise users.

So there are user groups like below.

- Individual users can access from anywhere
- Company A users can access from network A only
- Company B users can access from network B only
- Company C users can access from anywhere

What's the efficient way to control this access restriction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**Approach 1**

One approach is to create multiple IAM policies with IP restriction for each of these users and allow them to assume them using AWS Cognito Federated Identities and use the IAM authorizer at API Gateway. You can set the company as an attribute and create a rule in Cognito Federated Identities mapping the IAM policy. For example, check the following IAM policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {"NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": [
      "192.0.2.0/24",
      "203.0.113.0/24"
    ]}}
  }
}
```

Note: You need to grant access to API Gateway Endpoints using the IAM policy.

**Approach 2**

Another approach is to keep multiple User Pools for each company and link with a different Cognito Federated Identity Pools linked with IAM policies that have the IP filtering.At the API Gateway, you can use the IAM authorizer similarly.

**Approach 3**

Another approach is to use an AWS Custom Authorizer and filter the request based on IPAddress of the incoming request after looking at the Cognito ID Token and matching with Company (If the Company is stored as an attribute in UserPool).

Note: You need to use [Enhanced Request Authorizers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/) to access the headers with IP information.

Comment: I'll go with Approach 1. Thank you for solving my problem.